# Force iPhone to open Facebook's URL in Web Navigator (Safari, Chrome, Opera Mobile, etc)

Tags: ios, facebook, uiapplication, openurl

i have a simple question:

I can´t force the **[UIApplication sharedApplication] openUrl:**  to open the url in the web navigator, always open the Facebook app and don´t go to the facebook pages.

Answer (score 7):

I solve this problem adding the "**?ref=0**" in the url. It's works.

Comment: Where are you adding ?ref=0 ? Can you provide the full url?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what Facebook url are you using, however, to open Facebook in Web Navigator I'm using:

http://www.facebook.com/pages/DrMama/582190345150285

then:

```
fbProfile = @"http://www.facebook.com/pages/DrMama/582190345150285";
NSURL *fbURL = [NSURL URLWithString:fbProfile];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:fbURL];
```

That is opening Web Navigator without problem.

Comment: Thanks, yes I know... but if you have the Facebook App installed it's open that app.

Comment: No. With Facebook App installed, and calling a Facebook url with this format: http://www.facebook.com/pages/DrMama/582190345150285 my app is opening Safari.

Answer (score 0):

I use URL shortener to get around. There are a lot e.g. https://bitly.com/, http://goo.gl/

Bitly shortens a Facebook url to "http://on.fb.me/abc123", so it doesn't look that ugly. It even looks better than Google URL shortener in fact :)